# ManualResetEvent.WaitOne(1) waits more than 1ms?

Tags: vb.net, hid

I am acquiring data with an HID device. The code below is a rough outline of my timing mechanism.

```
Dim CANTimer as New System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch
Dim resetEvent as New Threading.ManualResetEvent(False)
....

CANTimer.Start()
ResetEvent.WaitOne(1)
CANTimer.Stop()
```

Timing this, I'll usually get times of 3ms, which is the delay I'd expect the HID transfer to take... and about every 4th or 5th iteration will take 20ms. These numbers don't really change regardless of what I set my timeout in milliseconds to be.

Why does the ResetEvent not timeout at one ms?

and.. Closer to the metal, why is it that the HID transfers seem to take either 3ms or 20ms (never 15ms, etc.)... What is happening when the transfer takes 20ms?

Comment: Interesting. I was looking at my HID transfer data and response times aren't 3ms to 20ms... they are 3ms OR 20ms. I was curious if setting a timeout to say 4ms would speed up the 20ms requests... by sending a new transmission packet to the HID device if I could force it to respond (and get 6ms send/receive instead of 20ms)

Comment: By the way Hans... I'd take that as the answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Timer resolution on Windows is only 15.625 msec by default. You can crank it up to a millisecond by pinvoking timeBeginPeriod(1) but this has a system-wide affect. Do treat time-outs like true timeouts, not a way to count milliseconds.

Comment: Just want to emphasize that `timeBeginPeriod` should only be used if you really need it.

Comment: So. The way I understand it, pinvoking timeBeginPeriod(1) might change the way other programs operate? We'd love to speed up our data transfer rate, but we should probably focus on harvesting more data on the embedded system and transferring those larger packets to windows, rather than speeding windows up to receive lots of small packets.